# What is an algorithm for finding the smallest sub tree of an unweighted directed graph for only a specific set of nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a unique problem and looking for a known fast algorithm for it. I have an unweighted but directed graph `G`. I then have a subset collection of nodes `S` existing in `G`. I want to find the minimum sub tree in `G` such that it contains all the nodes in `S`.

I so far found Chu-Liu/Edmonds algorithm but it is for finding the MST for all nodes in the graph.

Does anyone know how to do this for a subset of nodes?

Example:
[image]

If the picture is `G`. And `S` is the node set `{1, 6}`. Then the solution (smallest sub tree) is the subset graph of `{1, 3, 4, 6}` since it includes the nodes of `S`. It wouldn't be `{1, 3, 2, 5, 6}` (even though it includes the nodes of `S`) because that is larger.

Thanks

Comment: What does "minimum" mean, in an unweighted graph? Anyway, every spanning tree in $G$ will contain all the nodes in $S$.

Comment: minimum meaning least amount of nodes in the MST.

Comment: Also S is a subset of nodes in G, but for a specific S, its possible not all nodes in the MST is in G.

Comment: If you call it a spanning tree in $G$, then it had better include every node in $G$, so they all have the same number of nodes. If you don't want a spanning tree, you should call it something else. And if not all the nodes in the tree are in $G$, then where are those nodes that are not in $G$? $S$ is a subset of $G$, so I'm baffled.

Comment: I added an example above in my post to make it more clear.

Comment: I guess instead of MST, I'll call it a subtree. So to find the smallest subtree that contains all nodes of `S`.